# Is it possible to use Background Notifications in IOS programming without Apple Developer Program?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I want to test the Notifications idea on Xcode in a little app for my friends.
I searched online and found that I need certificates from Apple Developer Program to push notifications.
Is there a way to use the notifications without the certificates?
And if there isn't, Is there something similar I can do?
Thanks.

Comment: Well, you can use local notification which doesn't require any certificates, not sure about how you are going to implement push notification without having certificates from Apple Developer Program.

Comment: What do you mean by "local notification"?

Comment: refer here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction.html